# PHP: Make an Array value into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I´m making a form, and I want to change the value of the POST into a variable. 
But I'm doing it wrong somehow.

Check the sample:

```
$_POST['name'] = $name;
$_POST['age'] = $age;
$_POST['country'] = $country;
```

This error pops: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` on the first $_POST

Comment: You want to store the posted values in separate variabels? You have to write it in the oposite direction: $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: Either your question is worded backwards, or your code is written backwards. Are you trying to create a variable from the POST value? Or trying to change the POST values?

Comment: The error is on the previous line from the first $_POST. Update with that code please.

Comment: Why would be assigning variables to the post array?  Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @all Has anyone actually read the error? The compiler is telling him he put a variable right smack in the middle of something else. That variable is the first $_POST. Doesn't matter if he does a=b or b=a. The error is unrelated to your solutions.

Comment: @Khez: Yeah, it seems you and I are the only ones who read the error. Nobody else even mentioned that it's entirely possible to assign *to* the `$_POST` array, even if it's almost definitely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @AgentConundrum I used to do "special" redirects from time to time where I'd inject my own $_GET/$_POST and `include;die();` my main script file to get the flow re-started in another direction. It's an entirely valid assignment operation. Maybe unwise... but valid.

Comment: @Khez: It's probably also useful to do this for unit testing.

Comment: @Khez and @AgentConundrum: My bad for not reading all the text. But I thought OP had written the question incorrectly, and I didn't want to spend time answering it if that was not the real need. Glad you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While everyone else is entirely correct to point that you shouldn't be assigning values to the `$_POST` superglobal, it *is* possible for you to make such an assignment. The `$_POST` superglobal *is* just an array, after all, and so it acts like one.

The error you're seeing is because PHP is recognizing `$_POST['name']` as being part of the previous statement. Check to make sure that you have properly ended the previous statement (i.e. the line before `$_POST['name'] = $name` ends with a `;`).

You probably do want to be assigning `$_POST['name']` to a variable, rather than the other way around as you have it now, but that's not what's causing the error.

Comment: @Khez: Oddly, I was responding to your post-level comment while you were responding to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it a simple ; missing in the previous line. I also inverted to the A = B order that everybody stated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't programmatically set `$_POST` variables. These are set by the server based on what was `POST'ed` to that page(via forms or otherwise).

So I'm fairly sure you want:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
```

This is because the assignment operator works as such:

```
a = b
```

Set a to the value of b.

Answer (score 1):

go the other way:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignment works right to left, so to get the values **from** the **into** a variable you'd have to do:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
...
```

Your code above does not contain any syntax error, it must be from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You have this backwards, it should be:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];  
$age= $_POST["age"];  
$country= $_POST["country"];
```

The value to the right of the = gets assigned to the left.  As is you are trying to replace the post variable with an unassigned variable.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same error at:
$name = $_POST['name'];
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: @Gabriel check @AgentConundrum's response or my comment in your OP.